# MVC 2 with Entity Data Model returning Null for foreign keys

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am creating my first MVC 2 applicaiton. I've followed expamples in the books I have and created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model that auto generated the model.edms and model.designer.cs files. I then created a repository.cs file in my model folder to store my methods for retrieving data. When I use theses methods to retrieve an object from my tables the foriegn key attributes are returned null. Here is one of my methods

```
    private LanTracerEntities2 entities = new LanTracerEntities2();

    public Employee FindEmployee(string empId)

    {
        var emp =  from employee in entities.Employees
               where employee.LogIn == empId
               select employee;

        return emp.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

The employee table has the following columns:
ID
EmpFName
EmpLName
EmpInitial
Phone
LogIn
Email
LocID

LocID is a foriegn key linking it to the Location table. When I run the method it returns a value for every attribute but LocID. LocID is null. There is data in the table. This is not the only object I have that is returning null for foriegn key attributes. How can I get the method to return the FK values?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with MVC. It's more of a LINQ to Entities problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are comparing with the wrong property? Given the name of your parameter *I think* you might want to compare with the Id of the employee:

```
    var emp =  from employee in entities.Employees
           where employee.ID == empId
           select employee;
```

Having said that your primary key should be numeric int/bigint - if that's the case do this instead:

```
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(empId);
    var emp =  from employee in entities.Employees
           where employee.ID == id
           select employee;
```

If you want to include Location as part of your query results you can specifically ask for that:

```
var emp =  from employee in entities.Employees.Include("Location") 
           ..
```

This should populate the `Location` property in your employee record when you retrieve it.

Comment: Thank You I added the .Include statement and it is finally including fk data. Can I use this to bring in multiple FKs? If so would in format it .Include("FK1","FK2")

Comment: @user: Yes - you can chain Include statements, i.e. `entities.Employees.Include("foo").Include("bar")` I encourage you to check out the feature documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx